# Crear nuevo objeto usando map (o alternativas)

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
let logData = {
  name: { vmdl: "nombrePrueba",},
  lastName: { vmdl: "apellidoPrueba"},
  email: { vmdl: "emailPrueba" },
  password: { vmdl: "passPrueba" },
  role: {vmdl: "rolPrueba"},
}
```

Y quiero crear un nuevo objeto tal como `newObject` con los valores `vmdl` de `logData` en el mismo orden y lo consigo con lo siguiente:

```
let newObject= {
  name: "",
  lastName: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  rol: "",
};

const vmdls = Object.values(logData).map((v, i) => v.vmdl);
Object.keys(newObject).map((key, i) => {
  return newObject[key] = vmdls[i];
});
console.log(newObject)
```

Pero quisiera crear el nuevo objeto usando map (o alternativas), sin tener que usar un objeto externo (newObject) para inyectarle los valores vmdls que extraigo de `logData`. ¿Cómo podría lograrlo? Gracias por sus aportes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con un reduce, así:

```js
let logData = {
  name: { vmdl: "nombrePrueba",},
  lastName: { vmdl: "apellidoPrueba"},
  email: { vmdl: "emailPrueba" },
  password: { vmdl: "passPrueba" },
  role: {vmdl: "rolPrueba"},
}

const newObject = Object.entries(logData).reduce((obj, [key, {vmdl}]) => ({
   ...obj,
   [key]: vmdl
}), {});

console.log(newObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar las propiedades originales para generar el nuevo objeto, sin necesidad de tener el objeto "plantilla":

```js
let logData = {
  name: { vmdl: "nombrePrueba",},
  lastName: { vmdl: "apellidoPrueba"},
  email: { vmdl: "emailPrueba" },
  password: { vmdl: "passPrueba" },
  role: {vmdl: "rolPrueba"},
};

// cada entry es un array de dos elementos, la clave y el valor
// con map podemos "desanidar" el valor:
let entries = Object.entries(logData).map(entry => [entry[0], entry[1].vmdl]);

// hacemos el proceso inverso, con las entradas generadas montamos el nuevo objeto
let result = Object.fromEntries(entries);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes obtener un arreglo con el nombre de las propiedades el objeto usando [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) y luego recorrerlo usando [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) para copiar los datos en un nuevo objeto.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let logData = {
  name: { vmdl: "nombrePrueba",},
  lastName: { vmdl: "apellidoPrueba"},
  email: { vmdl: "emailPrueba" },
  password: { vmdl: "passPrueba" },
  role: {vmdl: "rolPrueba"},
}

let newObj = {};
Object.keys(logData).forEach(v => newObj[v] = logData[v].vmdl);
console.log(newObj)
```

---

Otra opción es usar [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) en lugar de `forEach`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let logData = {
  name: { vmdl: "nombrePrueba",},
  lastName: { vmdl: "apellidoPrueba"},
  email: { vmdl: "emailPrueba" },
  password: { vmdl: "passPrueba" },
  role: {vmdl: "rolPrueba"},
}

let newObj = Object.keys(logData).reduce((acc, v) => (acc[v] = logData[v].vmdl, acc), {});
console.log(newObj)
```